# Spring-Integration Groovy DSL + Grails

Tags: grails, spring-integration

I am looking for some example of SpringIntegration + Grails configuration, specially keen to see how the Groovy DSL for spring integration can be hooked into Grails application. All the examples from the DSL doc refers to load the flows from java / groovy main file, but I am trying to figure out how to define & use the flows in spring/Resources.groovy and inject them in my grails controllers.

Any Hint?